# Changing Windows process priority via command line

Tags: windows, command-line, process, priority

I want to change Windows process priority via command line.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The command line syntax:

```
wmic process where name="AppName" CALL setpriority ProcessIDLevel
```

**Example:**

```
wmic process where name="calc.exe" CALL setpriority 32768
```

or

```
wmic process where name="calc.exe" CALL setpriority "above normal"
```

**Priority:**

- idle: 64 (or "idle")
- below normal: 16384 (or "below normal")
- normal: 32 (or "normal")
- above normal: 32768 (or "above normal")
- high priority: 128 (or "high priority")
- real time: 256 (or "realtime")

Comment: [You can also do wildcards](http://codeslammer.wordpress.com/2009/02/21/wmic-wildcard-search-using-like-and/) `wmic process where "CommandLine like '%calc%'" CALL setpriority "below normal"`

Comment: Its possible to do the same for Background(low IO and memory priority) like in Process Explorer?

Comment: will this work even on "cmd.exe" from batch? ...batch that will start that cmd.exe?

Comment: Note: the first set of quotes is mandatory, so in other shells the quotes must be escaped (or double-quoted). In Cygwin: `wmic process where 'name="calc.exe"' CALL setpriority "idle"`

Comment: why is below/above normal value is so large and strange? And why is normal less than both idle and realtime?

Comment: Doesn't work on windows 8

Comment: Works fine on Window$ 10.0.17134.648 Enterprise x64.

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows XP

Comment: @phuclv Because they originally were process attribute bit masks defined a long time ago and more granularity needed later added as other bit definitions. That's also why 96 and the likes are invalid.

Answer (score 14):

A small addition.

You can also use string values instead of integers (easier to memorize) like that:

```
 wmic process where name="calc.exe" CALL setpriority "idle"
```

Possible values:
"idle", "low", "below normal", "normal", "above normal", "high priority", "realtime"

PS. Don't forget the quotes, especially if using multiple words in a string value

Comment: The first set of quotes is mandatory, even if not using multiple words. It must also be passed to the command, rather than being interpreted by the shell.

Comment: On win10 Pro 1809, "low" is not a recognized value - it throws an error.  using "Idle" causes the process to be displayed as "low" priority in task manager...

Answer (score 9):

From batch command line I would simply use PowerShell. This example starts calc.exe, finds its process and adjusts its priority class to "IDLE", aka LOW:

```
start /b /wait powershell.exe -command "calc.exe;$prog = Get-Process -Name calc;$prog.PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::IDLE"
```

Specify one of the following enumeration values: "`Normal, Idle, High, RealTime, BelowNormal, AboveNormal`"

Here is the same thing from PowerShell with split lines:

```
calc.exe
$prog = Get-Process -Name calc
$prog.PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::IDLE
```

Comment: What's the point of repeating what was already said before?

Comment: @harrymc It answers the original question, using PowerShell.

Comment: @harrymc - actually I am repeating what I said from DEC.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20693028/powershell-script-that-runs-in-background-changing-specific-process-priority-to/20694903#20694903

Comment: No problem. Just that I linked to something pretty similar.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to existing answers, the question *[Windows Equivalent of 'nice'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208/windows-equivalent-of-nice)*
lists some more solutions:

1. Using the [command START](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4332/1861282) in the command-prompt (CMD).
2. Using the free [ProcessTamer](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/proctamer/index.html) to set up a rule on the .exe
   that is automatically enforced whenever that process is started.
3. Using a PowerShell script [contained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4302/165358).
4. Using a VBScript script [contained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/675056/165358).

Additionally, the old [SetPriority](http://gilchrist.ca/jeff/SetPriority/) utility might still work, but I haven't tried it for many years now.

Some of these solutions may not work on system services or may need to be *Run as Administrator*.

Comment: The obvious snag with the vbScript solution is that it takes 23 lines of code to accomplish its task (i.e. set the priority level), where the START command takes only 2 lines to do so (one, at a pinch, hence it even works at a bare command prompt): _start "" /realtime /b /w program.exe_

Answer (score 3):

I am running Windows 7 64-bit.

The **wmic** command is *not* reliable. In my considerable experience, it fails unexpectedly for too many (mostly inexplicable) reasons.

The best possible command, because of its reliability, is the START command. The syntax is very simple (this is the 3-line run command for a **batch file**):

```
::  Boost thread priority
SET command=<program.exe> <options>
start "" /REALTIME /B /W  %command%
```

In my opinion its high degree of reliability stems from the fact that it sets the priority level with which the .exe program is launched, rather than trying to meddle with priority *after* the program has begun running with a different priority.

Answer (score 0):

https://sites.google.com/site/prioclick

Fixed priorities and automatic controls.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1087908)