# Change process priority using cmd

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, priority

Using the command

`wmic process where processid= 2140 CALL setpriority 128` (found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/620724/changing-windows-process-priority-via-command-line))

I am trying to change the priority of a specific process (PID 2140).

[image]

Running the command it gives me the following output:

[image]

Checking the specific process using TaskManager it still has prio "normal".

I tried to find the meaning for the "return value" but I do not find it. I think it is telling me an error.

What am I doing wrong and where do I find the error/return codes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error codes are listed on the official [technet help articles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx).

In this particular case Code 5 would mean Access denied.

> ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED
>   5 (0x5)
>   Access is denied.

You probably need to run the command from within the same user context or use an administrative access to change the process priority.

See also [Changing Windows process priority via command line](https://superuser.com/questions/620724/changing-windows-process-priority-via-command-line) for some more options. It's likely going to be easier to start the process with a given priority e.g. using [`START`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true).