# Possible to limit torrent speed when another device is connected to the network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing, bittorrent, throttling

Is there any way for me to be able to limit my overall torrent speed when another device is connected to the network?
I would like my desktop pc to throttle the download speed of any running torrents when my phone is connected to the wireless side of my network, and then go back to being unthrottled when my phone is not connected. Is this possible at all?

Requested info edit: 
 Torrent PC OS: Windows 10 Pro - 
Phone OS: Stock Android 7.1 with root - 
Router: Netgear D6000 (Ubiquiti EdgeRouter X when at home)

(have been away sorry for the slow update)

Cheers

Comment: Typically I would say you would need an up-stream device you can create Quality of Service (QoS) rules which is aware of both devices. There is a chance your router may offer something so worth a quick check.

Comment: However from the PC, one thing that might work as a hack would be to have a background script that "pings" your phone by some means, if it gets a response, then the script could lower the priority of the Torrent client process. If it stops responding it could restore the default priority.  I'm not sure how that would effect the download speed though. Can you test, using the info here: https://superuser.com/questions/620724/changing-windows-process-priority-via-command-line if changing the priority of the torrent process does also reduce it's download speed? Maybe test that first.

Comment: Agree with @helpinghand here, QOS would be the ideal solution. You just need to mark the torrent traffic as low priority. As long as your phone's traffic has I higher one it will automatically throttle the torrent traffic. **Please update the question with router and operating system information**.

Comment: @helpinghand lowering the task priority unfortunately does not influence the torrent(s) download speed, but i see what you are getting at.