# How to set low priority while compressing with wzzip.exe

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, compression

I have this in batch and the code works without `start /low`. While compressing with `wzzip` the CPU is 100% and all other programs hang.

So to fix this issue I've been trying to either set affinity or priority, but with `start /low` inserted I continue to get error:

> `Windows cannot find '-ez'`

Any help with this would be appreciated.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "%Path%\dirlist.txt"') do (
start /low "c:\program files\winzip\wzzip" -ez -md "%%a.zipx" "%%a"
CLS
```

Thanks for the feedback. With it I was able to make it run in priority low.

```
start "" /b /low /wait "c:\program files\winzip\wzzip.exe" -ez -md "%%~a.zipx" "%%~a"
```

It was very important to use `/wait` command otherwise if you are using a for loop the program wzzip.exe runs all instances at once instead of running one then waiting for it to complete before running another.

Additionally, I changed the cpu core usage to 1 by using `/affinity 0x1`

```
start "" /b /low /affinity 0x1 /wait "c:\program files\winzip\wzzip.exe" -ez -md "%%~a.zipx" "%%~a"
```

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

```all-bat
@echo off 

set "_wzzip="c:\program files\winzip\wzzip.exe"
for /f tokens^=* %%a in ('type "d:\Folder\Subfolder\dirlist.txt"
')do start "" /b /low /wait /affinity 0x1 "!_wzzip!" -ez -md "%%~a.zipx" "%%~a" && (
"%__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic.exe" process where 'name="wzzip.exe"' CALL setpriority "idle")
```

About:  *Windows cannot find `-ez`*, try to add `""` and `.exe` in:

> - *Edit*: Adding **[@author](https://superuser.com/users/1168848/these-arent-the-droids)** **[solution](https://superuser.com/q/1546056/969781)**:  **`/wait /affinity`**

```all-bat
start "" /b /wait /low /affinity 0x1 "!_wzzip!" -ez -md "%%~a.zipx" "%%~a"
```

You can replace the `%path%` variable with the full file `dirlist.txt`:

```all-bat
for /f tokens^=* %%a in ('type "%path%\dirlist.txt"')

for /f tokens^=* %%a in ('type "d:\Folder\Subfolder\dirlist.txt"')
```

Start your command by adding pertinent arguments/flags so that it starts in the background:

```all-bat
start "" /b /wait /low /affinity 0x1 "!_wzzip!" -ez -md "%%~a.zipx" "%%~a"
```

After running the command above in background, make a call to the `wmic` console setting the `wzzip.exe` process to `idle`

```all-bat
"%__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic.exe" process where 'name=wzzip.exe"' CALL setpriority "idle"
```

[√] **[Find](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)**

[√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

[√] **[wmic in Microsoft Documents /online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic)**

[√] **[wmic setpriority "idle" sources from @Bobs questio and answer](https://superuser.com/a/620725/969781)**